# Display Api data from strict model in swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am new to swift coding, I am trying to fetch data from API and was able to print data in the console as per below format after doing changes in model file.

```
Result(
    customerList: [
        walletApp.ResultItem(
            accountId: "00000023880",
            card: "5120"
        ),
        walletApp.ResultItem(
            accountId: "3880",
            card: "581"
        ),
        walletApp.ResultItem(
            accountId: "3881",
            card: "750"
        )
    ]
)
```

Below is my viewmodel code

```
import Foundation

class apiCall {
    func getUsers(completion:@escaping ([Result]) -> ()) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://myapi-call-ges-here")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response , error) in
     
            do{
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self,from: data!)
                print(result)
                
            }
            catch{
                print("Error:\(error)")
            }
         }.resume()
        }
}
```

Below is my STRUCT code

```
import SwiftUI

struct Result: Codable {
    let customerList:[ResultItem]
    
}

struct ResultItem:Codable{
    let accountId: String
    let card:String
}
```

Below is my VIEW page where i need to display accountId and card in a LIST

```
import SwiftUI

struct successLogin: View {
    @State var users: [Result] = []
    var body: some View {
        Text("USERS LIST")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .underline()
//        List(users){ user in
//
//            Text(Result)
//                .font(.headline)
//            Text(Result)
//                .font(.subheadline)
//        }
            
            .onAppear{
                apiCall().getUsers{(users) in self.users = users
                    
                }
            }
           //.padding()
    }
}
```

in the commented LIST code, what changes do i need to make to display data of **card** and **accountId**

Comment: Do you understand what the parameter to getUsers is and how and why you should use it in the function?

Comment: You’re not calling the completion with result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this approach:

```
struct successLogin: View {
    @State var users: [ResultItem] = []  // <-- here
    var body: some View {
        Text("USERS LIST")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .underline()
        
        List(users){ user in
            Text(user.accountId)  // <-- here
                .font(.headline)
            Text(user.card)       // <-- here
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
        .onAppear{
            ApiCall().getUsers { users in
                self.users = users
                
            }
        }
        //.padding()
    }
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let customerList:[ResultItem]
}

struct ResultItem: Codable, Identifiable { // <-- here
    let id = UUID()  // <-- here
    let accountId: String
    let card:String
}

class ApiCall {
    
    func getUsers(completion:@escaping ([ResultItem]) -> ()) { // <-- here
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://myapi-call-ges-here")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response , error) in
            // guard for data, todo
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self,from: data!)
                print(result)
                completion(result.customerList) // <-- here
            } catch {
                print("Error:\(error)")
                completion([]) // <-- here
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I fear, `ApiCall().getUsers { users in self.users = users }` won't work here. It is a (legacy) async call with a completion handler. We do not know, when this handler will be called. The view's `@State var users` data storage might or might not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM architecture

```
// ViewModel
final class SuccessLoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var users: Result = .init(customerList: [])

   func getUsers() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://myapi-call-ges-here")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response , error) in
     
            do{
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data!)
                self.users = result
                
            }
            catch{
                print("Error:\(error)")
            }
         }.resume()
        }
}
```

```
// SwiftUI View
struct successLogin: View {
    @ObservedObject model

    var body: some View {
        Text("USERS LIST")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .underline()
        List(model.users.customerList) { user in
            Text(user.accountId)
               .font(.headline)
            Text(user.card)
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
            .onAppear{
                model.getUsers()
            }
    }
}
```

I recommend using this approach.

(I wrote this without a compiler, so there may be errors, but the gist should be clear)

Comment: I would suggest to add proper error handling in the dataTask completion handler. :)  Also, you do not call the completion handler in the catch clause, (outch).  Furthermore, since you are already using a model that could be responsible for an improved loading logic, I would not call "model.getUsers()" in `onAppear`. Instead just let the view notify the model about the fact that it did appear, for example: call something `viewDidAppear()` and let the _view model_ decide if it needs to load or update data or not.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I agree with you! But I relied on the code that the author provided. I wanted to improve on an existing version, rather than offering a completely new turnkey solution. I think this will help to understand this practice better.